# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in Laravel-7 migration

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration, laravel-relations

When you are applying a foreign key using laravel migration it through this type of error

"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

The default structure of migration

```
User Table
---------

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Chat Table
---------

 Schema::create('chats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');


        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Our column size should not exactly the same size, take a look below.

```
$table->id();
This will create a big integer
```

AND

```
 $table->integer('user_id');
This will create a small integer that's why Our foreign key relations fails
```

**How to Fix this issue**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

OR

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
```

Add unsignedBigInteger and your problem will be solved.

Comment: you can also use `$table->foreignId('user_id')`

Comment: @apokryfos you are right, this is from laravel-7. " $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained(); "